# Input common-mode range vs output voltage (INA826) interpretation

Tags: analog, instrumentation-amplifier, texas-instruments, common-mode

I'm starting a new design using INA826 and analyzing the input common mode limitation, I do not understand the differences between this curves;

[image]

I mean, why in figures 11 and 12, gain and VS is not specified?

I must suppose that G is greater than 100? (according to gain evolution from figure 9)

Comment: [TA = 25°C, VS = ±15 V, RL = 10 kΩ, VREF = 0 V, and **G = 1 (unless otherwise noted)**](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina826.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I mean, why in figures 11 and 12, gain and VS is not specified?

[image]
Source:INA826

> I must suppose that G is greater than 100? (according to gain
> evolution from figure 9)

If you do suppose that G is more than 100, it will be on the outside of the red box by a little more than the G=100 line, so they don't graph it. You should be able to get an idea of if the gain will work with the G=100 line for gains over 100.